# Ionic Execution failed for task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: ionic-framework

I have build fresh ionic aplication, but after run ionic capacitor run android, the error show

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * What went wrong:
[capacitor]         Execution failed for task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[capacitor]         > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Any solution for this?

Comment: have you run `ionic cap sync` before building?